# Pinch Zoom for ImageView in Android

Tags: android

I have two ImageView in one activity , I want to apply pinch zoom for that two images.

If I pinch one image it should apply for both the ImageView.

Anyone suggest me how to do this.

this is my xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/imageview1" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:paddingLeft="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/imageview2" >
</ImageView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please Please Please! try some thing, show us your effort and then describe problem

Comment: Show your code and xml file.

Comment: At where your xml file here???

Comment: Or do a google search to get plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you don't want to write your own: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

If you do, the method that comes to mind would be to use a `ScaleGestureDetector` to detect pinches, override the onDraw method of the imageView, apply a scale to the canvas, and invalidate it so it redraws with the new zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly have in your mind, but one way to do it is that you can put your images in a RelativeLayout and then put that **RelativeLayout** in a custom [ZoomView](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93573/how-can-i-zoom-and-drag-the-multiple-image-in-relativelayout). This way when you zoom in, the whole view will be zoomed, including images inside.